# Parsing XML document into a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<comments>
<row Id="1" PostId="2" Score="0" Text="(...)" CreationDate="2011-08-30T21:15:28.063" UserId="16" />
<row Id="2" PostId="17" Score="1" Text="(...)" CreationDate="2011-08-30T21:24:56.573" UserId="27" />
<row Id="3" PostId="26" Score="0" Text="(...)" UserId="9" />
</comments>
```

What I'm trying to do is to extract ID, Text and CreationDate colums into pandas DF and I've tried following:

```py
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd
path = '/.../...'
dfcols = ['ID', 'Text', 'CreationDate']
df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

root = et.parse(path)
rows = root.findall('.//row')
for row in rows:
    ID = row.find('Id')
    text = row.find('Text')
    date = row.find('CreationDate')
    print(ID, text, date)
    df_xml = df_xml.append(pd.Series([ID, text, date], index=dfcols), ignore_index=True)

print(df_xml)
```

But the output is:

```
None None None
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As advised in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489576/why-does-concatenation-of-dataframes-get-exponentially-slower/36489724#36489724) by gold member Python/pandas/numpy guru, @unutbu:

> Never call DataFrame.append or pd.concat inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying.

Therefore, consider parsing your XML data into a separate list then pass list into the `DataFrame` constructor in one call outside of any loop. In fact, you can pass nested lists with list comprehension directly into the constructor:

```
path = 'AttributesXMLPandas.xml'
dfcols = ['ID', 'Text', 'CreationDate']

root = et.parse(path)
rows = root.findall('.//row')

# NESTED LIST
xml_data = [[row.get('Id'), row.get('Text'), row.get('CreationDate')] 
            for row in rows]

df_xml = pd.DataFrame(xml_data, columns=dfcols)

print(df_xml)

#   ID   Text             CreationDate
# 0  1  (...)  2011-08-30T21:15:28.063
# 1  2  (...)  2011-08-30T21:24:56.573
# 2  3  (...)                     None
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a minor change in your code

```
ID = row.get('Id')
text = row.get('Text')
date = row.get('CreationDate')
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Parfait solution, I wrote my version that gets the columns as a parameter and returns the Pandas DataFrame.

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<comments>
<row Id="1" PostId="2" Score="0" Text="(.1.)" CreationDate="2011-08-30T21:15:28.063" UserId="16" />
<row Id="2" PostId="17" Score="1" Text="(.2.)" CreationDate="2011-08-30T21:24:56.573" UserId="27" />
<row Id="3" PostId="26" Score="0" Text="(.3.)" UserId="9" />
</comments>
```

xml_to_pandas.py:

```
'''Xml to Pandas DataFrame Convertor.'''

import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd


def xml_to_pandas(root, columns, row_name):
  '''get xml.etree root, the columns and return Pandas DataFrame'''
  df = None
  try:

    rows = root.findall('.//{}'.format(row_name))

    xml_data = [[row.get(c) for c in columns] for row in rows]  # NESTED LIST

    df = pd.DataFrame(xml_data, columns=columns)
  except Exception as e:
    print('[xml_to_pandas] Exception: {}.'.format(e))

  return df


path = 'test.xml'
row_name = 'row'
columns = ['ID', 'Text', 'CreationDate']

root = et.parse(path)
df = xml_to_pandas(root, columns, row_name)
print(df)
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since pandas 1.3.0, there's a built-in pandas function [pd.read_xml](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) that reads XML documents into a pandas DataFrame.

```py
path = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<comments>
<row Id="1" PostId="2" Score="0" Text="(...)" CreationDate="2011-08-30T21:15:28.063" UserId="16" />
<row Id="2" PostId="17" Score="1" Text="(...)" CreationDate="2011-08-30T21:24:56.573" UserId="27" />
<row Id="3" PostId="26" Score="0" Text="(...)" UserId="9" />
</comments>"""

# or a path to an XML doc
path = 'test.xml'
pd.read_xml(path)
```

The XML doc in the OP becomes the following by simply calling `read_xml`:

[image: res]